# Not able to read results of SuggestComponent using SolrJ API

Tags: solr, autocomplete, solrj, autosuggest, solr5

I am using SuggestComponent to get auto suggest keywords. I configured search component and request handler correctly in solrconfig.xml. I am getting expected results also.

Now my problem is i am not able to read XML output using SolrJ api. i spent couple of hours on SolrJ API, but not able to find method to read suggested keywords.

My Java Code

```
SolrServer server = //solrserver object creation
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("qt", "/suggest");
params.set("q", q);
QueryResponse rsp = server.query(params);
**//How to read from QueryResponse?**
```

Here is my solrconfig.xml configuration

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>      
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>    
      <str name="field">name</str>
      <str name="weightField">reviewsNum</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
      <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Response:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">24</int>
</lst>
<lst name="suggest">
<lst name="mySuggester">
<lst name="a">
<int name="numFound">10</int>
<arr name="suggestions">
<lst>
<str name="term">JNTU <b>A</b>nantapur</str>
<long name="weight">2</long>
<str name="payload"/>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="term"><b>A</b>merican School of Bombay</str>
<long name="weight">1</long>
<str name="payload"/>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="term">
Society For <b>A</b>dvanced Study In Rehabilitation
</str>
<long name="weight">1</long>
<str name="payload"/>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="term"><b>a</b>mrita vishwa vidyapeetham</str>
<long name="weight">1</long>
<str name="payload"/>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="term">
shanmugha <b>a</b>rts science technology & research <b>a</b>cademy (sastra)
</str>
<long name="weight">1</long>
<str name="payload"/>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="term">Montesorri Hs <b>A</b>lampur</str>
<long name="weight">1</long>
<str name="payload"/>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="term"><b>A</b>ditya Ps Nehru Road Proddutur</str>
<long name="weight">1</long>
<str name="payload"/>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="term">Zphs <b>A</b>rakatavemula Rajupalem</str>
<long name="weight">1</long>
<str name="payload"/>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="term">Sri <b>A</b>ditya Ps,pamur Pamuru</str>
<long name="weight">1</long>
<str name="payload"/>
</lst>
<lst>
<str name="term">
ramakrishna mission vivekananda educational <b>a</b>nd research institute
</str>
<long name="weight">0</long>
<str name="payload"/>
</lst>
</arr>
</lst>
</lst>
</lst>
</response>
```

Comment: For temp fix, i am reading like this. List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();NamedList<Object> data = rsp.getResponse();
  LinkedHashMap spellInfo  = (LinkedHashMap)data.getVal(1);
  SimpleOrderedMap sugg = (SimpleOrderedMap)spellInfo.get("mySuggester");
  SimpleOrderedMap suggestions = (SimpleOrderedMap)sugg.get(q);
  ArrayList list = (ArrayList)suggestions.get("suggestions");
  for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
   SimpleOrderedMap o = (SimpleOrderedMap)list.get(i);
   String keyword = o.get("term").toString();
   keywords.add(keyword);
  }

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to access the [`SpellCheckResponse`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/SpellCheckResponse.html) property of the response:

```
rsp.getSpellCheckResponse()
```

This returns a SpellCheckResponse object, which contains the [`getSuggestions()`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/SpellCheckResponse.html#getSuggestions()) method, which in turn returns a List of [`SpellCheckResponse.Suggestion`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/SpellCheckResponse.Suggestion.html) objects.

```
List<SpellCheckResponse.Suggestion> suggestions = rsp.getSpellCheckResponse().getSuggestions()
```

You also want to use `setRequestHandler("/suggest")`, and not the `qt` parameter.

Comment: rsp.getSpellCheckResponse() is giving null. but rsp.getResponse()  is giving data.

Comment: MatsLindh,Here i am not using SpellCheckComponent class, rather i am using SuggestComponent class. So still response.getSpellCheckResponse() method will give results?